# htaccess always redirect POST request to GET request.

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm very new with .htaccess, and I'm having a problem with it.

I don't know why it always turn any post request into a GET request.

This is my .htaccess config:

```
RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+)/withdrawals https://sphere.social/api/social-network/withdrawals?user-id=$1
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It does not converts **post** request to **get**, this rewrite rule does the following :

1) if the request is for `users/{anydigit}/withdrawals`

2) Forward it to `https://sphere.social/api/social-network/withdrawals?user-id=`